# vscode: command for user input in debug launch config

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to do something similar to whats outlined in [this documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_attaching-to-nodejs) for selecting a process, except I want to just be able to input any string:

```
{
    "name": "Attach to Process",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
    "port": 9229
}
```

Is there a command that I can use to get any user input?  Ideally I could do something like this:

```
{
  "name": "Launch Chrome Debug",
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "url": "http://localhost:8080/?id=${command:UserInput}",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
}
```

That way I could specify the "id" param when I launch the debugger.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

v1.30 has added this functionality: [input variables during tasks and debug](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_30#_improved-user-input-variables-for-task-and-debug-configurations).

> For user input variables, we introduced a new variable category input,
>   which results in this syntax: `${input:variableName}`. This simple
>   syntax is not sufficient to present meaningful UI to the end user, so
>   we've introduced a new inputs section in launch.json and tasks.json,
>   where additional configuration attributes are specified.

[image: input example]

> Here is the list of supported attributes:
>
> id - The corresponding variable name for which these attributes are
>   used.
>
> type - The type of user input widget. In this release, promptString
>   (for a string InputBox) and pickString (for a string Quick Pick) are
>   supported.
>
> description - Descriptive text shown to the user.
>
> default - The default value to use if the user just presses Enter.
>
> A first example shows how to use a user input variable in a task
>   configuration (tasks.json):

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Echo input",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo ${input:echoPrompt}"
        }
    ],
    "inputs": [
        {
            "id": "echoPrompt",
            "description": "Please enter a value",
            "default": "default echo text",
            "type": "promptString"
        }
    ]
}
```

> Another example shows a user input variable for selecting between two
>   options in a debug configuration (launch.json):

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/${input:pickProgram}"
        }
    ],
    "inputs": [
        {
            "id": "pickProgram",
            "description": "Select client or server",
            "type": "pickString",
            "options": ["client.js", "server.js"],
            "default": "client.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

> We plan to combine user input variables with the existing
>   command-based variables so that user input variables can be
>   contributed by extensions.

Comment: This is great! Thanks for making me aware

Comment: this is great.  For the second config, I wonder if there is some way to run a task that would save the last input (when using `promptString`) and then update the input default