# how to pass arguments to a c++ file after using build to compile and run it in vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I would like to run my c++ file with vscode "Run c/c++ file" and at the same time have the resulting program accept a "input.txt" file as it's arugments

Here is the "task.json" file that i'm currently using:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "-std=c++17",
                "-Wshadow",
                "-Wall",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            },
            "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

It's currently only running the compiled c++ file so i have to type the inputs manually and i want to automate that.

Comment: `tasks.json` is for building. launch.json is for running or debugging. See the official documentation that explains the purpose of the 3 json files: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48273346/11107541 what do you mean "input.txt" as its arguments? you mean pass "input.txt" as a commandline argument? You mean pass the contents of the file as commandline arguments? you mean feeding the file contents to the standard input stream of the program?

Comment: I mean doing this "./app < input.txt"