# Open select File Dialog in launch.json

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need to create a launch.json file for visual studio code, which will be used to analyse a Linux core dump file.

Everything works fine when I set up "program" and "coreDumpPath" property statically in the launs.json file.

Also with an inputs section and type promptstring works everything fine. But this method only opens a text field, where path information needs to be typed in.

Instead, is it possible to bring up a file selection Dialog box to the user, where the file can be selected from the local file system?

Comment: you can use an extension I wrote [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#pick-file) use the command `extension.commandvariable.file.pickFile`

Comment: The linked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48273346/vscode-command-for-user-input-in-debug-launch-config) has answers how to use input variables for that. You could also go the "stupid simple" way of using `${file}`, opening the dump in VSCode, ignoring the error about it being large and binary, and then launching the debugging session from there.

Comment: You are right it doesn't show a file _picker_, only an input field where you could write or paste the file path. So although it achieves the goal of not having to hardcode the path, it's not the way the OP desires. I retracted the vote. - Still, input variables are the way to go. To achieve more than an input box, one could use the [command variable extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable), in particular its [`pickFile`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#pick-file) command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [command variable extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable), in particular its [`pickFile`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#pick-file) command:

```json
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "lldb",
      "request": "custom",
      "name": "Open a core dump",
      "initCommands": [
        "target create -c ${input:pickDumpFile}"
      ]
    }
  ], 
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "pickDumpFile",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.pickFile",
      "args": {
        "description": "Pick a core dump file"
      } 
    } 
  ] 
}
```

It has a ton of options to customize the behavior, please read the documentation for that. For example you might be interested in `fromFolder`, depending on your use case.